# How to publish report from jasper studio to jasper server

Tags: jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

How to publish report from jasper studio to jasper server?

will I publish the main report only or  Including the sub reports?

Comment: Please review the answer below and accept it if it solved your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open a report
2. Click the **Publish Report** button [image: Publish Report], located in the upper-right hand corner of the Designer.

The **Reporting Publishing Wizard** opens.

[image: Reporting Publishing Wizard]

3. Navigate the directory structure and choose the directory where you want to store your report.
4. Name the report unit. The report unit contains all report files. Click **Next**.

The **Select Resources** window opens.

[image: Select Resources]

5. Select any resources you want to upload with your report and check the box if you want to overwrite previous versions of those resources. Click **Next**.

The **Configure the data source** window opens.

[image: Configure the data source]

6. Select a data source, or no data source. Click **Finish**.

The report is uploaded to the server. If there are no errors, an appropriate message is shown.

Source: [Publishing a Report to JasperReports Server](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v60/publishing-report-jasperreports-server)

Comment: Do i have to publish my subreports too or just the main report?

Comment: I'm not sure, give it a try and see. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can publish report as given in Jasper [documentation](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v60/publishing-report-jasperreports-server).

You also have to publish subreport.